# Android App-Link: Xamarin app doesn't open on https URI

Tags: android, xamarin, deep-linking, applinks

I'm trying to open a Xamarin (Forms) app by using Chrome to browse to a certain URL. I followed (among others) this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/android/platform/app-linking

This is the activity:

```cs
[Activity(Label = "RecipeURLSchemeInterceptorActivity", NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask)]
[IntentFilter(
    new[] { Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
    DataScheme = "https",
    DataHost = "subdomain.domain.tld",
    DataPathPrefix = "/recipe",
    AutoVerify = true
)]
public class RecipeURLSchemeInterceptorActivity : Activity
{
    protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Code
    }
}
```

The URL I'm using to test the functionality is:

```
https://subdomain.domain.tld/recipe.php?s=17
```

The code works when not using https but a custom scheme (e.g. appname:// ...), but not when using https as the scheme.

I verified the domain ownership by uploading this file into https://subdomain.domain.tld/.well-known/assetlinks.json:

https://pastebin.com/iumfVsrj

Why doesn't my app open when I browse to the URL? If any more information is needed, don't hesitate to ask.

Thanks very much!

Comment: `...using Chrome to browse to a certain URL...` Are you typing that URL into chrome or using an html page-based hyperlink?

Comment: I've tried it by typing it into the browser and by redirecting using the location header…

Comment: It needs to be a page-based hyperlink to be properly evaluated

Comment: you could write an HTML page, do a redirect in the code ,then upload it to the server.